# AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.onItemClick swallows IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: android, android-listview, indexoutofboundsexception, android-adapter

I have a listView with the following `OnItemClickListener`:

```
mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(final AdapterView<?> parent, final View view, final int position, final long id) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
});
```

This will throw the exception as expected. However when I replace `IllegalArgumentException` with `IndexOutOfBoundsException`, the exception is not thrown as expected.

I went through the source code, but I could not find where `IndexOutOfBoundsException` was being caught.

Why can I see this strange behaviour? Is this behaviour documented anywhere?

Comment: If this is actually happening (and it seems unlikely to me that you aren't just missing something), then it would be in the framework.  Look in the ListView code for where it calls onItemClick.

Comment: I went through it several times, and this is what is happening. No extra code around it.

Answer (score 0):

Before going to check the exception first of all verify all the import statements.
and its could be also written as

```
    mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

Here we need to import AdapterView. ie

```
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
```

Its so easy ..

Comment: I confirmed that I am importing `android.widget.AdapterView`